# Hive tables not found when running in YARN-Cluster mode

Tags: apache-spark, hive, hadoop-yarn, apache-spark-sql, hortonworks-data-platform

I have a Spark (version 1.4.1) application on HDP 2.3. It works fine when running it in YARN-Client mode. However, when running it on YARN-Cluster mode none of my Hive tables can be found by the application.

I submit the application like so:

```
./bin/spark-submit 
    --class com.myCompany.Main 
    --master yarn-cluster 
    --num-executors 3 
    --driver-memory 4g 
    --executor-memory 10g 
    --executor-cores 1 
    --jars lib/datanucleus-api-jdo-3.2.6.jar,lib/datanucleus-rdbms-3.2.9.jar,lib/datanucleus-core-3.2.10.jar /home/spark/apps/YarnClusterTest.jar  
    --files /etc/hive/conf/hive-site.xml
```

Here's a excerpt from the logs:

```
5/12/02 11:05:13 INFO hive.HiveContext: Initializing execution hive, version 0.13.1
15/12/02 11:05:14 INFO metastore.HiveMetaStore: 0: Opening raw store with implemenation class:org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore
15/12/02 11:05:14 INFO metastore.ObjectStore: ObjectStore, initialize called
15/12/02 11:05:14 INFO DataNucleus.Persistence: Property hive.metastore.integral.jdo.pushdown unknown - will be ignored
15/12/02 11:05:14 INFO DataNucleus.Persistence: Property datanucleus.cache.level2 unknown - will be ignored
15/12/02 11:05:14 INFO storage.BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Registering block manager worker2.xxx.com:34697 with 5.2 GB RAM, BlockManagerId(1, worker2.xxx.com, 34697)
15/12/02 11:05:16 INFO metastore.ObjectStore: Setting MetaStore object pin classes with hive.metastore.cache.pinobjtypes="Table,StorageDescriptor,SerDeInfo,Partition,Database,Type,FieldSchema,Order"
15/12/02 11:05:16 INFO metastore.MetaStoreDirectSql: MySQL check failed, assuming we are not on mysql: Lexical error at line 1, column 5.  Encountered: "@" (64), after : "".
15/12/02 11:05:17 INFO DataNucleus.Datastore: The class "org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.model.MFieldSchema" is tagged as "embedded-only" so does not have its own datastore table.
15/12/02 11:05:17 INFO DataNucleus.Datastore: The class "org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.model.MOrder" is tagged as "embedded-only" so does not have its own datastore table.
15/12/02 11:05:18 INFO DataNucleus.Datastore: The class "org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.model.MFieldSchema" is tagged as "embedded-only" so does not have its own datastore table.
15/12/02 11:05:18 INFO DataNucleus.Datastore: The class "org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.model.MOrder" is tagged as "embedded-only" so does not have its own datastore table.
15/12/02 11:05:18 INFO metastore.ObjectStore: Initialized ObjectStore
15/12/02 11:05:19 WARN metastore.ObjectStore: Version information not found in metastore. hive.metastore.schema.verification is not enabled so recording the schema version 0.13.1aa
15/12/02 11:05:19 INFO metastore.HiveMetaStore: Added admin role in metastore
15/12/02 11:05:19 INFO metastore.HiveMetaStore: Added public role in metastore
15/12/02 11:05:19 INFO metastore.HiveMetaStore: No user is added in admin role, since config is empty
15/12/02 11:05:19 INFO session.SessionState: No Tez session required at this point. hive.execution.engine=mr.
15/12/02 11:05:19 INFO parse.ParseDriver: Parsing command: SELECT * FROM streamsummary
15/12/02 11:05:20 INFO parse.ParseDriver: Parse Completed
15/12/02 11:05:20 INFO hive.HiveContext: Initializing HiveMetastoreConnection version 0.13.1 using Spark classes.
15/12/02 11:05:20 INFO metastore.HiveMetaStore: 0: get_table : db=default tbl=streamsummary
15/12/02 11:05:20 INFO HiveMetaStore.audit: ugi=spark   ip=unknown-ip-addr  cmd=get_table : db=default tbl=streamsummary    
15/12/02 11:05:20 DEBUG myCompany.Main$: no such table streamsummary; line 1 pos 14
```

I basically run into the same 'no such table' problem for any time my application needs to read from or write to the Hive tables.

Posting hive-site.xml here for reference.

```
  <configuration>

    <property>
      <name>ambari.hive.db.schema.name</name>
      <value>hive</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>datanucleus.autoCreateSchema</name>
      <value>false</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>datanucleus.cache.level2.type</name>
      <value>none</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hive.auto.convert.join</name>
      <value>true</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hive.auto.convert.join.noconditionaltask</name>
      <value>true</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hive.auto.convert.join.noconditionaltask.size</name>
      <value>1968526677</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hive.auto.convert.sortmerge.join</name>
      <value>true</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hive.auto.convert.sortmerge.join.to.mapjoin</name>
      <value>false</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hive.cbo.enable</name>
      <value>true</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hive.cli.print.header</name>
      <value>false</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hive.cluster.delegation.token.store.class</name>
      <value>org.apache.hadoop.hive.thrift.ZooKeeperTokenStore</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hive.cluster.delegation.token.store.zookeeper.connectString</name>
      <value>worker1.xxx.com:2181,worker3.xxx.com:2181,worker2.xxx.com:2181</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hive.cluster.delegation.token.store.zookeeper.znode</name>
      <value>/hive/cluster/delegation</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hive.compactor.abortedtxn.threshold</name>
      <value>1000</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hive.compactor.check.interval</name>
      <value>300L</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hive.compactor.delta.num.threshold</name>
      <value>10</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hive.compactor.delta.pct.threshold</name>
      <value>0.1f</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hive.compactor.initiator.on</name>
      <value>true</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hive.compactor.worker.threads</name>
      <value>0</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hive.compactor.worker.timeout</name>
      <value>86400L</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hive.compute.query.using.stats</name>
      <value>true</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hive.conf.restricted.list</name>
      <value>hive.security.authenticator.manager,hive.security.authorization.manager,hive.users.in.admin.role</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hive.convert.join.bucket.mapjoin.tez</name>
      <value>false</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hive.default.fileformat</name>
      <value>TextFile</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hive.default.fileformat.managed</name>
      <value>TextFile</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hive.enforce.bucketing</name>
      <value>false</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hive.enforce.sorting</name>
      <value>true</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hive.enforce.sortmergebucketmapjoin</name>
      <value>true</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hive.exec.compress.intermediate</name>
      <value>false</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hive.exec.compress.output</name>
      <value>false</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hive.exec.dynamic.partition</name>
      <value>true</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode</name>
      <value>nonstrict</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hive.exec.failure.hooks</name>
      <value>org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.hooks.ATSHook</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hive.exec.max.created.files</name>
      <value>100000</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hive.exec.max.dynamic.partitions</name>
      <value>5000</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hive.exec.max.dynamic.partitions.pernode</name>
      <value>2000</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hive.exec.orc.compression.strategy</name>
      <value>SPEED</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hive.exec.orc.default.compress</name>
      <value>ZLIB</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hive.exec.orc.default.stripe.size</name>
      <value>67108864</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hive.exec.orc.encoding.strategy</name>
      <value>SPEED</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hive.exec.parallel</name>
      <value>false</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hive.exec.parallel.thread.number</name>
      <value>8</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hive.exec.post.hooks</name>
      <value>org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.hooks.ATSHook</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hive.exec.pre.hooks</name>
      <value>org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.hooks.ATSHook</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hive.exec.reducers.bytes.per.reducer</name>
      <value>67108864</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hive.exec.reducers.max</name>
      <value>1009</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hive.exec.scratchdir</name>
      <value>/tmp/hive</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hive.exec.submit.local.task.via.child</name>
      <value>true</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hive.exec.submitviachild</name>
      <value>false</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hive.execution.engine</name>
      <value>tez</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hive.fetch.task.aggr</name>
      <value>false</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hive.fetch.task.conversion</name>
      <value>more</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hive.fetch.task.conversion.threshold</name>
      <value>1073741824</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hive.limit.optimize.enable</name>
      <value>true</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hive.limit.pushdown.memory.usage</name>
      <value>0.04</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hive.map.aggr</name>
      <value>true</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hive.map.aggr.hash.force.flush.memory.threshold</name>
      <value>0.9</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hive.map.aggr.hash.min.reduction</name>
      <value>0.5</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hive.map.aggr.hash.percentmemory</name>
      <value>0.5</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hive.mapjoin.bucket.cache.size</name>
      <value>10000</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hive.mapjoin.optimized.hashtable</name>
      <value>true</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hive.mapred.reduce.tasks.speculative.execution</name>
      <value>false</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hive.merge.mapfiles</name>
      <value>true</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hive.merge.mapredfiles</name>
      <value>false</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hive.merge.orcfile.stripe.level</name>
      <value>true</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hive.merge.rcfile.block.level</name>
      <value>true</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hive.merge.size.per.task</name>
      <value>256000000</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hive.merge.smallfiles.avgsize</name>
      <value>16000000</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hive.merge.tezfiles</name>
      <value>false</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hive.metastore.authorization.storage.checks</name>
      <value>false</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hive.metastore.cache.pinobjtypes</name>
      <value>Table,Database,Type,FieldSchema,Order</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hive.metastore.client.connect.retry.delay</name>
      <value>5s</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hive.metastore.client.socket.timeout</name>
      <value>1800s</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hive.metastore.connect.retries</name>
      <value>24</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hive.metastore.execute.setugi</name>
      <value>true</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hive.metastore.failure.retries</name>
      <value>24</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hive.metastore.kerberos.keytab.file</name>
      <value>/etc/security/keytabs/hive.service.keytab</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hive.metastore.kerberos.principal</name>
      <value>hive/_HOST@EXAMPLE.COM</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hive.metastore.pre.event.listeners</name>
      <value>org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.security.authorization.AuthorizationPreEventListener</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hive.metastore.sasl.enabled</name>
      <value>false</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hive.metastore.server.max.threads</name>
      <value>100000</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hive.metastore.uris</name>
      <value>thrift://host.xxx.com:9083</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hive.metastore.warehouse.dir</name>
      <value>/apps/hive/warehouse</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hive.optimize.bucketmapjoin</name>
      <value>true</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hive.optimize.bucketmapjoin.sortedmerge</name>
      <value>false</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hive.optimize.constant.propagation</name>
      <value>true</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hive.optimize.index.filter</name>
      <value>true</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hive.optimize.metadataonly</name>
      <value>true</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hive.optimize.null.scan</name>
      <value>true</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hive.optimize.reducededuplication</name>
      <value>true</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hive.optimize.reducededuplication.min.reducer</name>
      <value>4</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hive.optimize.sort.dynamic.partition</name>
      <value>false</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hive.orc.compute.splits.num.threads</name>
      <value>10</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hive.orc.splits.include.file.footer</name>
      <value>false</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hive.prewarm.enabled</name>
      <value>false</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hive.prewarm.numcontainers</name>
      <value>3</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hive.security.authenticator.manager</name>
      <value>org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.security.ProxyUserAuthenticator</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hive.security.authorization.enabled</name>
      <value>false</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hive.security.authorization.manager</name>
      <value>org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.security.authorization.plugin.sqlstd.SQLStdConfOnlyAuthorizerFactory</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hive.security.metastore.authenticator.manager</name>
      <value>org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.security.HadoopDefaultMetastoreAuthenticator</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hive.security.metastore.authorization.auth.reads</name>
      <value>true</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hive.security.metastore.authorization.manager</name>
      <value>org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.security.authorization.StorageBasedAuthorizationProvider</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hive.server2.allow.user.substitution</name>
      <value>true</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hive.server2.authentication</name>
      <value>NONE</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hive.server2.authentication.spnego.keytab</name>
      <value>HTTP/_HOST@EXAMPLE.COM</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hive.server2.authentication.spnego.principal</name>
      <value>/etc/security/keytabs/spnego.service.keytab</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hive.server2.enable.doAs</name>
      <value>false</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hive.server2.logging.operation.enabled</name>
      <value>true</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hive.server2.logging.operation.log.location</name>
      <value>${system:java.io.tmpdir}/${system:user.name}/operation_logs</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hive.server2.support.dynamic.service.discovery</name>
      <value>true</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hive.server2.table.type.mapping</name>
      <value>CLASSIC</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hive.server2.tez.default.queues</name>
      <value>default</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hive.server2.tez.initialize.default.sessions</name>
      <value>false</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hive.server2.tez.sessions.per.default.queue</name>
      <value>1</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hive.server2.thrift.http.path</name>
      <value>cliservice</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hive.server2.thrift.http.port</name>
      <value>10001</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hive.server2.thrift.max.worker.threads</name>
      <value>500</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hive.server2.thrift.port</name>
      <value>10000</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hive.server2.thrift.sasl.qop</name>
      <value>auth</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hive.server2.transport.mode</name>
      <value>binary</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hive.server2.use.SSL</name>
      <value>false</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hive.server2.zookeeper.namespace</name>
      <value>hiveserver2</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hive.smbjoin.cache.rows</name>
      <value>10000</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hive.stats.autogather</name>
      <value>true</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hive.stats.dbclass</name>
      <value>fs</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hive.stats.fetch.column.stats</name>
      <value>true</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hive.stats.fetch.partition.stats</name>
      <value>true</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hive.support.concurrency</name>
      <value>false</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hive.tez.auto.reducer.parallelism</name>
      <value>true</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hive.tez.container.size</name>
      <value>5632</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hive.tez.cpu.vcores</name>
      <value>-1</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hive.tez.dynamic.partition.pruning</name>
      <value>true</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hive.tez.dynamic.partition.pruning.max.data.size</name>
      <value>104857600</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hive.tez.dynamic.partition.pruning.max.event.size</name>
      <value>1048576</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hive.tez.input.format</name>
      <value>org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveInputFormat</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hive.tez.java.opts</name>
      <value>-server -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -XX:NewRatio=8 -XX:+UseNUMA -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:+ResizeTLAB -XX:+PrintGCDetails -verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hive.tez.log.level</name>
      <value>INFO</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hive.tez.max.partition.factor</name>
      <value>2.0</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hive.tez.min.partition.factor</name>
      <value>0.25</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hive.tez.smb.number.waves</name>
      <value>0.5</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hive.txn.manager</name>
      <value>org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.lockmgr.DummyTxnManager</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hive.txn.max.open.batch</name>
      <value>1000</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hive.txn.timeout</name>
      <value>300</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hive.user.install.directory</name>
      <value>/user/</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hive.vectorized.execution.enabled</name>
      <value>true</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hive.vectorized.execution.reduce.enabled</name>
      <value>false</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hive.vectorized.groupby.checkinterval</name>
      <value>4096</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hive.vectorized.groupby.flush.percent</name>
      <value>0.1</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hive.vectorized.groupby.maxentries</name>
      <value>100000</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hive.zookeeper.client.port</name>
      <value>2181</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hive.zookeeper.namespace</name>
      <value>hive_zookeeper_namespace</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hive.zookeeper.quorum</name>
      <value>worker1.xxx.com:2181,worker3.xxx.com:2181,worker2.xxx.com:2181</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName</name>
      <value>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword</name>
      <value>hive</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>
      <value>jdbc:mysql://host.xxx.com/hive?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName</name>
      <value>hive</value>
    </property>

  </configuration>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I posted this same question on the Hortonworks community, and I resolved the issue with the help of [this](https://community.hortonworks.com/answers/5819/view.html) answer.

The gist of it is this: when submitting the application, the `--files` argument has to come before the `--jars` argument, and the copy of `hive-site.xml` to use is the one in the Spark `conf` dir, not in `$HIVE_HOME/conf/hive-site.xml`. Hence:

```
  ./bin/spark-submit \
  --class com.myCompany.Main \
  --master yarn-cluster \
  --num-executors 3 \
  --driver-memory 1g \
  --executor-memory 11g \
  --executor-cores 1 \
  --files /usr/hdp/current/spark-client/conf/hive-site.xml \
  --jars lib/datanucleus-api-jdo-3.2.6.jar,lib/datanucleus-rdbms-3.2.9.jar,lib/datanucleus-core-3.2.10.jar \
  /home/spark/apps/YarnClusterTest.jar
```

Comment: I was having similar problems. code worked in spark-shell but not via spark-submit - first issue was "table not found". Ultimately solved it as very much like Ton Torres did. Order of app jar, files and jars is important - was seeing "javax.jdo.JDOFatalUserException: Class org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory was not found".

Comment: Thanks!  Just wanted to note that the inclusion of the 3 datanucleus jars was important (I had other jars I was already including and overlooked the datanucleus ones, thinking the order was the only catch)

Comment: It helped me too, I had this exception during running the `saveAsTable` in `pyspark`.

```py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o67.saveAsTable.
: java.io.IOException: Failed on local exception: java.io.IOException: com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: Protocol message end-group tag did not match expected tag.; Host Details : local host is: "localhost"; destination host is: "localhost":10000; 
  at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapException(NetUtils.java:776)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to fetch data using Hive CLI, then use the same hive-site.xml in your Spark job.

The only reason could be the location of metastore defined in hive-site.xml.

Comment: thanks for the quick response. I am able to work with Hive using the CLI, but where would I find the hive-site.xml that CLI uses? I wasn't the one responsible for setting up and configuring our cluster, so I'm not too sure. I used `find` and there were a couple of entries. I did try some of them (including submitting the app without providing hive-site.xml at all) such as: "/etc/hive/2.3.2.0-2950/0/hive-site.xml", "/etc/spark/2.3.2.0-2950/0/hive-site.xml", "/usr/hdp/current/hive-client/conf/hive-site.xml" but I keep getting the same result.

Comment: usually it is $HIVE_HOME/conf/hive-site.xml. Check for environment variable "echo $HIVE_HOME" to get the directory used by your Hive installation.

Comment: strange, $HIVE_HOME isn't defined. I guess the hadoop environment variables aren't defined for the user I'm logging in with. Not sure why this is the case, but as far as I know, our cluster was installed using only the Ambari wizards. In any case, I did some searching and found that "/usr/hdp/current/hive-client/conf/hive-site.xml" should be the right one for HDP but I get the same result. Posting hive-site.xml for reference.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure if this is significant but I logged onto each of the cluster nodes and found that one of them doesn't have Spark installed. I wonder if this could be causing the problem?

Comment: We are concerned about the metastore URL defined by property "javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL". This states the location of metadata about the Hive tables. HDP recommends to use MySQL (default is derby) for metastore, so my strong hunch is that your cluster also leverages mySQL DB. You can also try checking the location defined by  $HIVE_CONF_DIR environment variable. default location is same as what you have defined "/usr/hdp/current/hive-client/conf/hive-site.xml".  In case nothing works then you need to contact your administrator for actual path of hive-site.xml.

Comment: I'm still waiting on the admins to reply regarding `$HIVE_HOME` so I'll update as soon as they do. In the meantime, I took a look at the value of "javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL", which is `<value>jdbc:mysql://host.xxx.com/hive?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true</value>`. Looking at the [documentation](http://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.3.0/bk_upgrading_hdp_manually/content/start-hive-20.html), I'm thinking this value should have port number and "/mysql" instead of "/hive"?

Comment: I figured out that the "/hive" in the connection URL is actually the schema/database name of the metastore in MySQL, so "/hive" is correct. I tried using `jdbc:mysql://host.xxx.com:3306/hive?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true` but unfortunately, I'm still encountering the issue.