# Error in pyspark with udf: You must build Spark with Hive. Export 'SPARK_HIVE=true' and run build/sbt assembly

Tags: python, hive, pyspark

I'm trying to run this code in Pyspark 1.6.2 using Pre-built for Hadoop 2.6 in Windows 7 professional

Everything works fine till the point where i define the udf. Can you give some pointers. Do I need to compile Spark with hive ? Then what is the use of the pre-built for Hadoop 2.6. I cannot change the C:\tmp\hive permissions as I'm not the system admin. Could that be the reason for this error message ?

```
from pyspark import  SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

rdd = sc.parallelize([('u1', 1, [1 ,2, 3]), ('u1', 4, [1, 2, 3])])
df = rdd.toDF(['user', 'item', 'fav_items'])
# Print dataFrame
df.show()

from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType

function = udf(lambda item, items: 1 if item in items else 0, IntegerType())

df.select('user', 'item', 'fav_items', function(col('item'),   col('fav_items')).alias('result')).show()
```

Then i get this error:

```
You must build Spark with Hive. Export 'SPARK_HIVE=true' and run build/sbt assembly
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\yrxt028\Downloads\spark-1.6.2-bin-hadoop2.6\spark-1.6.2-bin-hadoop2.6\python\pyspark\sql\functions.py", line 1597, in udf
    return UserDefinedFunction(f, returnType)
  File "C:\Users\yrxt028\Downloads\spark-1.6.2-bin-hadoop2.6\spark-1.6.2-bin-hadoop2.6\python\pyspark\sql\functions.py", line 1558, in __init__
    self._judf = self._create_judf(name)
  File "C:\Users\yrxt028\Downloads\spark-1.6.2-bin-hadoop2.6\spark-1.6.2-bin-hadoop2.6\python\pyspark\sql\functions.py", line 1569, in _create_judf
    jdt = ctx._ssql_ctx.parseDataType(self.returnType.json())
  File "C:\Users\yrxt028\Downloads\spark-1.6.2-bin-hadoop2.6\spark-1.6.2-bin-hadoop2.6\python\pyspark\sql\context.py", line 683, in _ssql_ctx
    self._scala_HiveContext = self._get_hive_ctx()
  File "C:\Users\yrxt028\Downloads\spark-1.6.2-bin-hadoop2.6\spark-1.6.2-bin-hadoop2.6\python\pyspark\sql\context.py", line 692, in _get_hive_ctx
    return self._jvm.HiveContext(self._jsc.sc())
  File "C:\Users\yrxt028\Downloads\spark-1.6.2-bin-hadoop2.6\spark-1.6.2-bin-hadoop2.6\python\lib\py4j-0.9-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py", line 1064,
l__
  File "C:\Users\yrxt028\Downloads\spark-1.6.2-bin-hadoop2.6\spark-1.6.2-bin-hadoop2.6\python\pyspark\sql\utils.py", line 45, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\yrxt028\Downloads\spark-1.6.2-bin-hadoop2.6\spark-1.6.2-bin-hadoop2.6\python\lib\py4j-0.9-src.zip\py4j\protocol.py", line 308, in g
_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling None.org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.
: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: The root scratch dir: /tmp/hive on HDFS should be writable. Current permissions are: rwx--
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:522)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.ClientWrapper.<init>(ClientWrapper.scala:204)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.IsolatedClientLoader.createClient(IsolatedClientLoader.scala:238)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.executionHive$lzycompute(HiveContext.scala:218)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.executionHive(HiveContext.scala:208)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.functionRegistry$lzycompute(HiveContext.scala:462)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.functionRegistry(HiveContext.scala:461)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.UDFRegistration.<init>(UDFRegistration.scala:40)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.<init>(SQLContext.scala:330)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.<init>(HiveContext.scala:90)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.<init>(HiveContext.scala:101)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:234)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:381)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:214)
        at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.invokeConstructor(ConstructorCommand.java:79)
        at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.execute(ConstructorCommand.java:68)
        at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:209)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: The root scratch dir: /tmp/hive on HDFS should be writable. Current permissions are: rwx------
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.createRootHDFSDir(SessionState.java:612)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.createSessionDirs(SessionState.java:554)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:508)
        ... 21 more
```

Comment: do you have `hive` installed separately? or have you just downloaded spark and using default configurations(hive)?

Comment: The hive is not installed separately. I am using the pre-built configuration for hadoop 2.6. I have always used pyspark on my mac, this is the first time dealing with udfs on Windows.

Answer (score 2):

you need to create `hive-site.xml` file in `$SPARK_HOME/conf` location. in this file you can override `scratch dir` path. These are the important configurations that you should include in `hive-site.xml` file but you can check this [link for other settings](https://github.com/apache/hive/blob/master/data/conf/hive-site.xml) if you get some other error:

```
<!-- Hive Execution Parameters -->
<property>
  <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
  <value>${test.tmp.dir}/hadoop-tmp</value>
  <description>A base for other temporary directories.</description>
</property>

<!--
<property>
  <name>hive.exec.reducers.max</name>
  <value>1</value>
  <description>maximum number of reducers</description>
</property>
-->

<property>
  <name>hive.exec.scratchdir</name>
  <value>${test.tmp.dir}/scratchdir</value>
  <description>Scratch space for Hive jobs</description>
</property>

<property>
  <name>hive.exec.local.scratchdir</name>
  <value>${test.tmp.dir}/localscratchdir/</value>
  <description>Local scratch space for Hive jobs</description>
</property>
<property>
  <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>
  <value>jdbc:derby:;databaseName=${test.tmp.dir}/junit_metastore_db;create=true</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName</name>
  <value>org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver</value>
</property><property>
  <!--  this should eventually be deprecated since the metastore should supply this -->
  <name>hive.metastore.warehouse.dir</name>
  <value>${test.warehouse.dir}</value>
  <description></description>
</property>

<property>
  <name>hive.metastore.metadb.dir</name>
  <value>file://${test.tmp.dir}/metadb/</value>
  <description>
  Required by metastore server or if the uris argument below is not supplied
  </description>
</property>

<property>
  <name>test.log.dir</name>
  <value>${test.tmp.dir}/log/</value>
  <description></description>
</property>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my hive-site.xml, I just had the following code:

```
<configuration>



<property>
  <name>hive.exec.scratchdir</name>
  <value>${/tmp1/hive}/scratchdir</value>
  <description>Scratch space for Hive jobs</description>
</property>

<property>
  <name>hive.exec.local.scratchdir</name>
  <value>${/tmp1/hive}/localscratchdir/</value>
  <description>Local scratch space for Hive jobs</description>
</property>



</configuration>
```

This post also helped me:

[What's hive-site.xml including in $SPARK_HOME looks like?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34216766/whats-hive-site-xml-including-in-spark-home-looks-like)

So instead of /tmp/hive , whose permissions I couldn't change, I created another folder /tmp1/hive.  Thanks a ton @BigDataLearnner.  There is another way to  override the directory by using  spark-env.sh -- I tried it but it didn't work

Code for spark-env.sh:

```
SPARK_LOCAL_DIRS=/tmp1/hive
SPARK_PID_DIR=/tmp1
```

Comment: This has not worked for me but the extended one by @Ronak Patel did.